# Set Text when there is click on list-view of dialog-box in android?

Tags: android, listview, dialog

> I am building an android application where On click of an image button
>   an dialog-box is appear.
>
> That has an list-view. Now the problem is how can I set the text-view
>   with the item is select from list of dialog-box.
>
> Here is my code of dialog-box

```
        public void start() {

        final CharSequence[] items = {
                "Beginner","Amateur","Semi Pro","Pro","Legend"
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Rank Your self");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

> Now I want on click of pro value of text-view at that time text-view1
>   set = beginner.

Answer (score 0):

define a new textview globally before onCreate and then search this textview using the view that you create in the dialog box.This will be like

```
TextView textbox;

textbox=(Textview) view.findViewById(R.id.textbox1);
textbox.settext();
```

if you need to edit this text then use edittext. view here is the custom dialog design.Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks!! can you please tell How I set the value of item of alert dialog box!

Comment: Well, this may depend on your choice of list type. There is an  exception example using the ListAdaptor [Using List in android ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) or for more simple list just create a spinner on the dialog box and fill with custom string array values(Beginner,Expert,etc).